# Unable to upload large file in MS Graph Onedrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using PUT method to upload in Onedrive

```
url= https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//users/{user-id}/drive/items/{item-path}:/{filename}:/content

var response = MSGraphHelper.InvokeGraphPUTStream(url, streamcontent)
```

The above is working properly but only for below 4MB file
I added a condition to support large file upload.

```
if (response == "RequestEntityisTooLarge")
{
sessionUrl = https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//users/{userId}/drive/items/{item-path}/createUploadSession
var uploadUrl = MSGraphHelper.InvokeGraphPost(url, null)
```

I got the uploadUrl from the POST method above but when I do the PUT method using the uploadUrl, I got "Bad Request" error.

I don't know what went wrong.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that your request is in the format similar to below example?  I was able to get this working in Postman to create an upload session.  The request body is optional.

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive/root:/PostmanCreatedFile1:/createUploadSession

Additional syntax for HTTP requests can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0#http-request